# How to match a jumbled string using regular expression

Tags: regex, string, python-3.x

I want to solve a case where i know what all will be contents of the string output.. but i am not sure about the order of the contents inside the output..

say, the expected contents of my output are `['this','output','can','be','jumbled','in','any','order']`..

and the output can be `'this can in any order jumbled output be'`, or `'this order  in any can output jumbled be'`

How do i write a regular expression in python to solve this case??

Comment: Are you saying you need permutation? Please clarify as i dont understand your question

Comment: yes right.. my output may have all permutations of a given set of words...

Comment: What's the actual *problem* you're trying to solve, and why do you think regex is the right way to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually feasible. For example using `^(?=.*this)(?=.*output)(?=.*can)(?=.*be)(?=.*jumbled)(?=.*in)(?=.*any)(?=.*order)`.

For each word, we simply enclosed it in a positive lookahead (assert what follows could be matched from current position), with any characters occuring before.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PrWcTP/1).

I'm not an expert at python, but I'm sure you could build it dynamically.

Comment: awesome.. it doesn't satisfy just one case.. say my string is ''this output can be jumbled in any order others' then i expect the regExp to fail, since the word 'others' is not expected in the output string.. but the regExp doesn't do a strict check..

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I can't help with the Python to do the processing - the Python you see is a suggestion from the regex-tool that I used. Your question is also unclear about whether you require EXACTLY one match of EACH of your expected words or whether a single matching word would also qualify...so these fine details will be left as homework to the interested reader ;-)

Here's a suggestion to get you started:

```
reobj = re.compile("this|output|can|be|jumbled|in|any|order", re.VERBOSE | re.DOTALL)
match = reobj.search(subject)
if match:
    # match start: match.start()
    # match end (exclusive): match.end()
    # matched text: match.group()
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```